# I get an exception when I try to reverse engineer a database in EF5 code first

Tags: entity-framework

This video shows me how to use Code First from an existing database.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj572367

So I use nuget to install EF Power Tools and I select my project, right click and choose;
Entity Framework -> Reverse Engineer Code First.
I select the database as outlined, but I get the following exception when I click OK;

```
System.Data.ProviderIncompatibleException: The provider did not return a ProviderManifestToken string. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: This operation requires a connection to the 'master' database. Unable to create a connection to the 'master' database because the original database connection has been opened and credentials have been removed from the connection string. Supply an unopened connection. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Login failed for user 'ictdev'.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.CompleteLogin(Boolean enlistOK)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnection owningObject)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnection owningObject, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, TimeoutTimer timeout)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(SqlConnection owningObject, TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, String newPassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SqlConnection owningObject, Boolean redirectedUserInstance)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateNonPooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPoolGroup poolGroup)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlProviderServices.UsingConnection(SqlConnection sqlConnection, Action`1 act)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlProviderServices.UsingMasterConnection(SqlConnection sqlConnection, Action`1 act)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlProviderServices.UsingMasterConnection(SqlConnection sqlConnection, Action`1 act)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlProviderServices.GetDbProviderManifestToken(DbConnection connection)
   at System.Data.Common.DbProviderServices.GetProviderManifestToken(DbConnection connection)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Data.Common.DbProviderServices.GetProviderManifestToken(DbConnection connection)
   at System.Data.Entity.Design.EntityStoreSchemaGenerator.GetProviderSchemaMetadataWorkspace(DbProviderServices providerServices, DbConnection providerConnection)
   at System.Data.Entity.Design.EntityStoreSchemaGenerator.CreateStoreSchemaConnection(String providerInvariantName, String connectionString)
   at System.Data.Entity.Design.EntityStoreSchemaGenerator..ctor(String providerInvariantName, String connectionString, String namespaceName)
   at Microsoft.DbContextPackage.Handlers.ReverseEngineerCodeFirstHandler.ReverseEngineerCodeFirst(Project project)
```

So the question is how do I fix this?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

I found the solution on the comments of the webpage of the EF Power Tools product;
http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/72a60b14-1581-4b9b-89f2-846072eff19d

In connection wizard, Advanced should be clicked and the value of Persist Security Info should be True.

If anyone can answer the original question and explain what is going on when you do this, I might tick them the answer!

Answer (score 0):

I deleted the existing connection and added a new one with correct credentials.
It works !