# Connecting to MS SQL Server on EC2 instance via WCF Application

Tags: c#, sql-server, wcf, connection-string, remote-desktop

I have a WCF application and a test client interface on my local machine.

I need to connect to the SQL Server database on an Ec2 instance.

This is my connection string:

```
<add name="MyDBContext" 
     connectionString="Data Source=ec2-11-11-11-11.compute.amazonaws.com\AMAZONA-AAAAAA,1433;Initial Catalog=TestDB;Trusted_Connection=False;Persist Security Info=True;Integrated Security=False" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

I have implemented following changes: (based on solutions I found on the net)

- Permit SQL Server on EC2 to to allow remote connections
- Enable TCP/IP on 1433
- Allow all ICMP ports on Amazon EC2 Management Console
- Disabled firewall currently to test(But then allow for SQL Server and  SQL Server Browser)

I am getting the following error:

> The provider did not return a ProviderManifestToken string.
>
> This operation requires a connection to the 'master' database. Unable to create a connection to the 'master' database because the original database connection has been opened and credentials have been removed from the connection string. Supply an unopened connection.

Code :

On aspx page =>

```
lblResult.Text = myServiceClient.getUserList("mytoken");
```

On Service Page =>

```
public string getUserList(string token)
{
MyDBContext db = new MyDBContext();
List<User> users = db.User.Where(u => u.Active == "Y").ToList();
var userList = users.Select(u => new { Name = u.Name });
return javaScriptSerializer.Serialize(new { response = userList});
}
```

Comment: Please, show us **your code** that is trying to connect and execute something (we can't see your screen, nor read your mind .....)

Comment: Thanks for your reply Marc. The code is pretty direct.
Will update the question

Comment: Have you tried [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13623805/i-get-an-exception-when-i-try-to-reverse-engineer-a-database-in-ef5-code-first) or [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19977141/this-operation-requires-a-connection-to-the-master-database)

Comment: Thanks for suggestions. But "Persist Security Info = True" is already added in my connection string