# Entity Framework Power Tools not work

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, entity-framework-6

I have a problem: I can't generate POCO from database with [Entity framework Power Tools Beta 4](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/72a60b14-1581-4b9b-89f2-846072eff19d) in my project.

I did try in Visual Studio 2012 and did try too in Visual Studio 2013 and don't work.
But that's was working in the last year (the last time when I used the Power Tools). Have any new problem?

And in the last year I used with EF5 and now with EF6...

Comment: Hello Priscila! I just tested this with latest everything (VS2013 Update 3 & EF6.latest) and had no problem. Do you get any type of error?

Comment: Hello @JulieLerman (hey, come to Brazil) so don't have any message error. Is just like "work" but "not work", no message error, no POCO, nothing. I can show the output messages but any message is abouth any error

Comment: Stupid question: Did you update the EF Power Tools, only the latest version Works with EF6 (0.9.0.0) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was security. I was needing set to true the  Persist Security in the Advanced Wizard.

> I found the solution on the comments of the webpage of the EF Power Tools product; http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/72a60b14-1581-4b9b-89f2-846072eff19d
>   In connection wizard, Advanced should be clicked and the value of Persist Security Info should be True.
>   If anyone can answer the original question and explain what is going on when you do this, I might tick them the answer!

by @arame3333 [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13623805/i-get-an-exception-when-i-try-to-reverse-engineer-a-database-in-ef5-code-first).

I don't know the motive for EF told me a message "Ready" if have one problem, but okay, this fixed my problem;